# how to get country name/code from any nu

Tags: android

Can anyone please tell me how to find country name from any number?

For example, Suppose i entered +91773654398 on edittext and on onclick i want to show the number is from INDIA.

I hope my query is clear.

Thanks & Regards,
Mona

Answer (score 1):

Simple: http://countrycode.org/ will list all countries and their prefix. Just create the appropriate lookup table.

Comment: Is there any way to find the country code through android API

Comment: I don't know about android, but this kind of data doesn't change often. Just create a lookup file in your app and use it locally.